# Getting error with const char

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I am trying to implement the functions below, but the output for foo() is a bunch of nonsense. I tried to run the debugger and didn't see any problems inside the append function. But the total variable in foo() isn't properly assigned the value "abcdef". Any ideas why?

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"foo is"<<endl;
    foo();
    return 0;
}

const char* append(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    string s(s1);
    s += s2;
    return s.c_str();
}

void foo() {
    const char* total = append("abc", "def");
    cout<<total;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because in `append()`, you returned `s.c_str()`; then, `s` is destructed, which means that the pointer returned is invalidated immediately.

Let `append()` return `std::string` to solve this issue.

```
std::string append(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    return std::string(s1).append(s2);
}

void foo() {
    std::string total = append("abc", "def");
    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Edited with possible fixes.

Comment: static local is pretty bad advice.

Comment: Yeah... although it's the "fix" with minimal code change.

Comment: So what? Why suggest doing a bad job when you could do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

*Undefined Behaviour*. `c_str` is only valid for the lifetime of `s` (and only then if `s` is not modified in any way). Once `append` has returned, `s` is out of scope. **Boom!**

One fix is to have `append` return a `std::string`.

Comment: +1 for `Boom!` (and correct answer, of course - had to add some characters to comment)

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* append(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    string s(s1);
    s += s2;
    return s.c_str();
}
```

The variable `s` is local to the function. It is destroyed when the function returns. That means that the value that you return, `s.c_str()`, points to memory that has been deallocated. De-referencing that memory results in undefined behaviour.

The rule with `c_str()` is, loosely put, that the value it returns is guaranteed to be valid until either the string object is modified or destroyed.

Simply put, you should stop using C strings unless you need to use them for interop. Your function should be:

```
string append(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    return s1 + s2;
}
```

Comment: Returning reference to local variable is as dangerous as returning pointer to local variable.

Comment: @timrau Yes, that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer from `append()` that is not valid when the function returns.

```
string s(s1);
```

defines a object in `append()`. It is destroyed when you return from the function. Hence, the returned value of `s.c_str()` is not valid in `foo`.

You can change your code to be:

```
string append(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    string s(s1);
    s += s2;
    return s;
}

void foo() {
    string total = append("abc", "def");
    cout<<total;
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

`return s.c_str();` : you return pointer obtained from temporary variable `s`.

You may fix your problem in two ways -

1. Return std::string by value from `append`.
2. Pass to `append` pointer to fill it with data -

> ```
> void append(const char* s1, const char* s2, char* out) {
>   string s(s1);
>   s += s2;
>   strncpy(out, s.c_str(), s.size()+1);
> }
>
> void foo() {
>   char total[7] = {0}; //should be enough to carry appended string + '\0'
>   append("abc", "def", total);
>   cout<<total;
> }
> ```